# How to draw multiple bitmaps on one screen?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-drawable

I was wondering how I would go about drawing multiple bitmaps on one screen. I want to have a drawing area that I can scroll across multiple bitmaps and view the drawing that are on each bitmap. For example there would be an 2x2 tiled area that I want to scroll across. I'm having trouble figuring out how I would go about showing part of either 2 or 4 bitmaps while I would be scrolling.

EDIT: This is what it would look like

[image]

Comment: Can u show a pictorial representation of what u want to achieve?

Comment: You should have your view larger than screen (lets assume 4 times of image) which will make it scrollable. Now, you will need to set your bitmaps b1, b2, b3, b4 in above required manner. This will solve your problem I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating your won implementation of a viewgroup using this model:

```
public class MyLayout extends ViewGroup{
    public MyLayout(Context c, AttributeSet attr){
        super(c, attr);

        //Add this to be albe to draw by yourself
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public onDraw(Canvas c){
        super.onDraw(c);

        //Do all your drawing in here
        //You can use canvas.drawBitmap etc...
    }
}
```

This is a good tutorial for a custom viewgroup on Android Dev page:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as answered with the checkmark on the left